# Three children on RelativeLayout does not get place to be shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to show four direct children on a Relative Layout where first one is a EdiText (in 'gone' visibility) and second one is LinearLayout with a TextView and ImageView and third is a ListView and fourth is another LinearLayout.

ListView gets over all children. I am posting below the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/scrollview"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context="com.antoinecampbell.gcmdemo.GcmActivity$PlaceholderFragment">
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/recepient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:hint="Number"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:visibility="invisible">
            <requestFocus />
</EditText>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_below="@+id/recepient" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="Preview"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

      <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageShow"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abs__ic_go"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"/>        




</LinearLayout>
  <ListView android:id="@+id/listMessages"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
          android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
          android:divider="#00000000"
          android:listSelector="#00000000"               
        />
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/listMessages"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/enter_message_text"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="text" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"/>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/frameView"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:visibility="gone">
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/emojicons"            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        class="com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconsFragment"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
            android:background="@drawable/angry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now I tried using LinearLayout with scrollview inside it, it's now not scrolling the listview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/recepient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:hint="Number"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:visibility="invisible">
            <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_small"
        android:text="Preview"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>

      <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageShow"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abs__ic_go"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"/> 

       <ListView android:id="@+id/listMessages"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayout1"
          android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
          android:divider="#00000000"
          android:listSelector="#00000000"               
        />


    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/listMessages"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
            android:id="@+id/name_edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_small"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/enter_message_text"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="text" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="visible"/>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:id="@+id/frameView"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:visibility="gone">
        <fragment
        android:id="@+id/emojicons"            
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        class="com.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconsFragment"/>
        </LinearLayout>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/send_message_button"
            android:background="@drawable/angry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"             
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @EranGoldin I want to place someviews on this layout where someviews are not visible and with options they will be visible. With RelativeLayout on top, increase of Listview occupying other views like, it gets over bottom linear layout and top edittext. With Linear Layout, listview does not scroll

Answer (score 2):

The ListView will go over other elements because you've not given it any relative positions. In a relative layout, every element will be default appear at (0,0) (ie the top left corner of the view) unless it's given a `layout_below`, `layout_alignBottom` etc parameter to determine where it's drawn.

So in this case, you 'resumably want the `ListView` to have `android:layout_below="@id/LinearLayout1` and the `bottomview` similarly `android:layout_below="@id/listMessages`.

Comment: If you want the views to be one after another vertically, is there a reason you aren't using a `LinearLayout` instead?

Comment: The problem is when the size of the listview increasing.. it takes over the place of the bottomview(LinearLayout) which should be happening. No there is no issue using LinearLayout however I dont know how to put the bottomview on bottom of the top container.

Comment: I think, this is a scroll issue, should I add a scrollview inside Relative layout and add a linearayout onto it to cover all its children

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xml as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edNumber"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="Number"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edNumber"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="linear layout text" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/llBottom"
        android:layout_below="@id/llLayout" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ababab"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Bottom Bar text" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```